# std::is_same else static assert

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert, is-same

I like to to specialize a function with respect to a template type. This works fine with `std::is_same`.

Now, I like the code to not compile, if a not specialized type is given.

```
template <typename T>
constexpr double get(const T& item) const {
    if (std::is_same<T, SOME_TYPE>::value)
        return item.get();
    if (std::is_same<T, SOME_OTHER_TYPE>::value)
        return -1.0;
    else {
        // Compile time error, if this branch is created.
        static_assert(false, "Getter not implemented for Type");
        return -1.0;
    }
}
```

This snippet does not compile, with the error message

> error: static assertion failed with "Getter not implemented for Type"

although the function is only instantiated with `SOME_TYPE` or `SOME_OTHER_TYPE`.

How can I make sure at compile time, that no others types than `SOME_TYPE` or `SOME_OTHER_TYPE`  are used?

Comment: use constexpr if

Comment: `static_assert` is checked at compile time, `if`-`else` is at runtime, so the `else` block still needs to compile, which is when the assertion fails. Perhaps `if constexpr` would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way is doing something like this:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr double get(const T& item) const {
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<T, SOME_TYPE>::value || std::is_same<T, SOME_OTHER_TYPE>::value,
        "Getter not implemented for Type");
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, SOME_TYPE>::value) {
        return item.get();
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, SOME_OTHER_TYPE>::value) {
        return -1.0;
    }
}
```

Note that your compiler needs to support C++17 so you can replace `if` with `if constexpr`.

EDIT: The `constexpr if` is needed here to avoid compilation error if `SOME_OTHER_TYPE` does not have `get()` member method. Therefore I have changed the code

Answer (score 2):

If the presented code is what you want (i.e. each block are independent with each other), simply use overload functions.

```cpp
constexpr double get(const SOME_TYPE& item){
   return item.get();
}
constexpr double get(const SOME_OTHER_TYPE&){
    return -1;
}
```